# Any performance implications of moving SqlDataReader to external function?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlclr

Given the following SQLCLR function:

```cs
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void ExecSQL(string sql, string connectionString)  
{
    WindowsIdentity clientId = null;
    WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = null;
    clientId = SqlContext.WindowsIdentity;
    try
    {
        try
        {
            impersonatedUser = clientId.Impersonate();
            if (impersonatedUser != null)
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {

                    //** HERE I WILL HAVE MULTIPLE VARIATIONS OF FETCHING THE SQLDATAREADER
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                    SqlDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader();
                    impersonatedUser.Undo();
                    SqlContext.Pipe.Send(r);
                }
            }
            else
            { throw new Exception("Impersonation failed."); }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (impersonatedUser != null) { impersonatedUser.Undo(); }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Are there any performance or other ramifications of moving this section:

```cs
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                SqlDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader();
```

out into a separate `GetDataReader()` method?

I ask because I know I am going to want to load data readers for many different scenarios (Sql text, Stored Procedure, Table Valued Function, Scalar Function, etc), so I would like to encapsulate each of those different implementations into their own function rather than having a big switch statement in the middle of this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any performance or other ramifications

Not that I can think of or have run into. Of course, when it comes to performance-related questions of this nature, I always recommend testing it out to see which is better, because anyone answering questions can always be wrong, and there are definitely cases of "accepted" answers being incorrect. Your software running on your system, however, is the definitive answer :-).

---

Beyond that, there are a few notes about the code fragment shown in the question.

1. You *could* move the `impersonatedUser.Undo();` to just after the `connection.Open();`. It was only needed to establish the connection. But, then again, perhaps it would be cleaner to keep the Impersonation handling in the main method and not move just the `Undo()` to the new method.

   OR, you could also keep the `connection.Open();` in the main method here instead. You are going to have to pass along the `connection` object in either case.
2. You could wrap the `impersonatedUser = clientId.Impersonate();` in an `if` condition, testing the `connectionString` to see if it is `"Context Connection = true;"`. This would allow you to use the Context Connection, which otherwise won't work since it can't be used with Impersonation. I suppose you can just re-work the current `if (impersonatedUser != null)` since that test would no longer be valid (the new test would only care if `impersonatedUser` was `null` if the Context Connection wasn't being use.
3. `WindowsImpersonationContext` is Disposable, so it would be better to move your `finally` block to the outer `try`, and add `impersonatedUser.Dispose();` after the `Undo()`.

Comment: have you worked with Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo before, specifically retrieving DefaultValue for StoredProcedures and UserDefinedFunctions?   I think I've got it mostly figured, but who knows how many edge cases I'm missing or future traps I'll fall into.  Sometimes (always?) it makes me want to cry how difficult SQL Server makes things!

Comment: @tbone No, I haven't played with SMO that much. I have updated a project that used it and got to see a little in terms of how it works, but that's about it. Maybe one of these days you can share with me what you are working on as I might be able to provide more guidance knowing the bigger picture. If interested, I can be contacted via the Contact Us page on the [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com) site.

Comment: I will definitely contact you as I would very much like to know your opinion.  :)